# How to change the order in which the rules are checked when using react hook form?

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

[Snack link](https://snack.expo.dev/@tayyabreact/rules-validation-sequence-react-hook-form)

I have an input field for phone numbers. I've added three rules for validation:

1. There should be no characters. This is done through a regex.
2. Input length must be 12 digits. This is done through minLength & maxLength rules.

**What's currently happening:**
When I type a non-digit character, I get the error message for the minLength & maxLength rules.

**What I want:**
When I type a non-digit character, it should show the error message of the first rule.

**My question:**
Is there a way to set the order in which the rules are checked?

Comment: According to this issue: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/1387#issuecomment-612249492 the ordering feature is still in pending state. you may try using yup or other validation schema to enforce ordering.